Derivatives of a rotation tensor intended to rotate bases of a symmetric 2nd order tensor
Let $A = \sum_i \lambda_i N_i \otimes N_i$ and $B= \sum_j \mu_j n_j \otimes n_j$ , be the two symmetric and independent 2nd order tensors and their respective spectral decompositions. Let R be the rotation tensor such that the operation, $B' = R.B.R^{T}$, rotates the bases of B to that of A. Then, deducing that $R = \sum_k N_k \otimes n_k$, what are its derivatives with respect to A, i.e., $\frac{\partial R_{pq}}{\partial A_{mn}} = ??$
Edit 1:
Trial 1: I have tried perturbing the $A$ tensor directly, where $Ap_{ij} = A_{ij} + pert*0.5*\delta_{ij} + pert*0.5*\delta_{ji}$. Then, obtained the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the $Ap$ tensor, remade the rotation tensor, $R = \sum_k Np_k \otimes n_k$ , to get the derivative as: $\frac{\partial R_{pq}}{\partial A_{mn}} = (Rp_{kl}-R_{kl})/pert$. But strangely, this only works for high values of pert ~ 1.0, but not always and is inconsistent as A and B evolve in my computations. Typically, to do derivatives by perturbation I use pert ~ 1e-8.
Trial 2: I have also tried the linear perturbation solution to get $\frac{\partial N_{i}}{\partial A_{mn}}$ and then used $\frac{\partial R_{kl}}{\partial A_{mn}} = \sum \frac{\partial N_{k}}{\partial A_{mn}} \otimes n_k$. This doesn't work either. I checked $\frac{\partial N_{i}}{\partial A_{mn}}$ in the context of $\frac{\partial A_{kl}}{\partial A_{mn}} = sym(I_4)$ with $I_4$ being the 4th order identity tensor's symmetric part, and I do not get the result. But when I use Serrin's representation to get $\frac{\partial (N_{i} \otimes N_{j})}{\partial A_{mn}}$ things work. I don't think a closed form solution exists to go from $\frac{\partial (N_{i} \otimes N_{j})}{\partial A_{mn}}$ to $\frac{\partial N_{i}}{\partial A_{mn}}$.

Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Could you edit your post to show some of your thoughts?
